# How to get Azure AD token in web app silently C#

Tags: azure, active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

i need to get Azure token in my app (C#) to perform Graph API operations on users, but without `sign in` all the time when app invoked (app must be full automate, working in timer job) so i have a question how to made process of token acquiring fully automate (without user)?

All that I found about this topic:
[Get access without a user](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/auth_v2_service#supported-app-scenarios-and-resources)
But I failed to recreate it.

Comment: "But I failed to recreate it." What issues did you come across? What didn't work? Did you get error messages? On my current project we're using a, what we call, 'Machine to Machine' AAD application that can access specific resources without user authentication. So it _is_ possible. Without enough relevant information, we won't be able to help you.

Comment: I tried to create a console app to make a call like in example to get token and then put it in my MS Graph API request to get info. But i didn`t get a token in response.

Answer (score 1):

The OAuth2 flow you are describing is called the "Client Credentials Grant" and is in detail described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-authentication-scenarios#daemon-or-server-application-to-web-api).

In short it is relevant in this case and works like this:

> First, user interaction is not possible with a daemon application,
>   which requires the application to have its own identity. An example of
>   a daemon application is a batch job, or an operating system service
>   running in the background. This type of application requests an access
>   token by using its application identity and presenting its Application
>   ID, credential (password or certificate), and application ID URI to
>   Azure AD. After successful authentication, the daemon receives an
>   access token from Azure AD, which is then used to call the web API.

[image: Application Identity with OAuth 2.0 Client Credentials Grant]

Have a look at [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-code-samples#server-or-daemon-application-to-web-api) implementation to see how it is done in code.

Answer (score 1):

Using OAuth On-Behalf-Of works exactly what you describe. Which On-Behalf-Of method, there is no user interaction to obtain the user's consent to access to the downstream API (e.g. Graph API). In other words, the user identity & permission is silently delegated in a full request chain. In a real-world corporate environment, your app would be normally authenticated by another identity provider (e.g. Active Directory) not Azure AD, which after then requests authorization to Azure AD OAuth endpoint.

When requesting access token, you must set its type is `requested_token_use=on_behalf_of`

Here is reference to POST to the endpoint https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-v2-protocols-oauth-on-behalf-of

Here is the reference of SSO authentication with OAuth On-Behalf-Of https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/add-ins/authenticate-a-user-with-an-sso-token