# C# AzureAD joined device - retrieve token for Graph API silently

Tags: c#, .net, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-msal

**I want to create Graph API client as logged in user. The device is Azure active directory joined device.**
[Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-authentication-flows#integrated-windows-authentication-iwa) says I should use Integrated windows authentication. But it ends up with exception: "*The system cannot contact a domain controller to service the authentication request*". This is expected because I want this to work from any network. Can this be done silently?

My actual code:

```
var authProvider = new DelegateAuthenticationProvider(async (request) => {
var result = await pca.AcquireTokenByIntegratedWindowsAuth(scopes).ExecuteAsync();

request.Headers.Authorization =
    new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", result.AccessToken);
});
var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(authProvider);
```

Comment: `DelegateAuthentication` means let users signed in and then generate the access token. I'm afraid it can't be done  silently.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @*Miroslav Adamec* for your question about to *create and get access token from azure ad silently*. It will surely be a valuable addition to the SO community. For the same purpose as stated by @***Tiny Wang***, posting your comment as an answer as it will be easy for other people with same issue to find it .

"*Looking at your code which you are using `DelegateAuthentication` refers to allowing users to sign in before generating the access token.*"

Also as stated in the given [**`MS DOC`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-authentication-flows#constraints-for-iwa) followings are need to be done before trying,
as IWA is a silent flow

- The user of your app must have given their permission to use it earlier.
- To use the application, the tenant admin must have given prior permission to all users in the tenant.

For more information please refer the below links:-

- **MICROSOFT DOCUMENT**|[***Get access on behalf of a user***](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-user).
- **SO THREAD**| [***How to get Azure AD token in web app silently C#***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49444751/how-to-get-azure-ad-token-in-web-app-silently-c-sharp).